# RenameField in ItextSharp not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext

I am using a pdfstamper and RenameField function to renam a pdf form field usinf itextsharp. But form fields are not getting renamed. It returns a false value. What I need to do now?

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PDF_PATH);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Test Out.pdf", FileMode.Create)) {
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
    AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
    fields.RenameField("oldFieldName", "newFieldName");
    stamper.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to rename using the full field's name? According to what I've read, you can only change "Person.Name" to "Person.Firstname" but **not** "Person.Name" to "Name"

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description that a software developer should give when asking a question on an internet forum. That's a problem description most commonly employed by standard users that do not understand or care about how computers work. Or how developers work, for that matter. I'm the original developer of iText and I know renameField works for me. Maybe it doesn't work for you because of a false assumption you've made. You saying it doesn't, sounds like you saying "Bruno, you're ugly." That's inconsiderate, unfriendly and untrue.

Comment: as every developer know Itextsharp is a great tool and every functionality built on that will work. I never meant that fields.RenameField never works, and I am not the right person to state that. I Just meant that in y specific situation it does not working. Since you are an ItextShatp developer you can tell me exception cases. In my case my pdf form was reader extended, so ItextSharp is unable to rename the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found answer for this question after a small research. I was trying to rename a pdf form field, which is a reader extended for 2D bar coding.  I had extended that pdf form for user editing, using adobe reader extension. So all the pdf form fields in that form are mapped to a barcode field within the form. That is not supported by adobe itself. In order to rename these kind of pdf form fields, we have to go for adobe live cycle, which will remove the reader extensions and will allow us to rename the field. Anyway thanks everyone for your valuable comments.